# Benchmarking Two Functions

Tags: c, visual-c++, performance

I am trying to check the time spent in two functions to compare them.

The functions take two backiterators as inputs.

these two are called inside one function.

```
void b_mark()
{
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
         timer1.start();
         function1(std::back_inserter(itr1));
         timer1.stop();


         timer2.start();
         function2(std::back_inserter(itr2));
         timer2.stop();

    }
}
```

It turns out that the function I call first takes more time and does not matter if it is 
function1 or function2.

What can be the general reason for this?

The timer is a wrapper to the `std::clock()`.

Comment: Code of timer would be more helpful here. Good probability of finding the problem lies in timer code.

Answer (score 1):

The time you're measuring includes the time for `std::back_inserter(...)`.  Could it be that this takes more time the first time you call it, e.g. for initialization?

Comment: I do not think so because the results are identical for both lists.

Answer (score 1):

Whenver you want to measure something, you have to make sure that:

- each measurement situation is exactly the same as all others - this includes generating same startup data, closing open resources before opening them again, etc
- you repeat the measured step enough times, so that the results are a) measurable, b) statistically significant
- the measurement functions/objects themselves are correct

In your case I suspect that:

- you measure each function call once, which may make the result meaningless - either because of system clock resolution, system resources allocation - and probably for many more reasons
- you may be operating on the same colleciton, which may be modified during the first call; the first call may, for example, allocate a large amount of memory in the collection, while the second only uses it
- your `timer` class may be incorrect and cause the result to be invalid

In short: this test case seems like a not reliable one and its results are likely to be invalid.

Try modifying the code like this:

```
void b_mark()
{
    int count = 10000;
    timer1.start();
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        resetItr(itr1);
        function1(std::back_inserter(itr1));
    }
    timer1.stop();


    timer2.start();
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        resetItr(itr2);
        function2(std::back_inserter(itr2));
    }
    timer2.stop();
}
```

Comment: Actually I tested it for about 100 tests. Inside the function nothing modified other than the std::lists provided which are different. The timer has no issues involved.

Comment: @cowboy 100 tests may be nothing for a function which takes several nanoseconds.

Comment: Infact this takes seconds so I believe it is enough, isn't it? I do not know if this is due to lack of memory. But the thing is the 1st function is the one which is slow.